# Разные заголовки одного поста Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть ли возможность вывести на одной странице пост с одним заголовком, а на другой этот же пост но с другим?

Comment: Можно использовать для создания второго заголовка custom fields

Comment: Ну как бы вариант, я так сделал с надписями которые на посте разные, но нету других способов?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте метабокс с полем для второго заголовка и используйте его а нужном месте.